# Change Mousepointer on hover over button

Tags: html, button

So, the standard cursor when you have nothing selected. Normally, when you hover over a button, the cursor changes to a hand. I have a simple button like this:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

But it does not change to the hand when it is over the button. How can change that the cursor so it changes into a hand?

Comment: what is your difficulty in reading the doc? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: `button { cursor: pointer }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cursor: pointer` to change the cursor.
For example -

```css
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

For more information on the `cursor` property see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).